# How to add two separate unrelated predicates to a single fetchrequest in NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have a simple app which has a Table View controller performing a NSFetchedResultsController based fetchRequest and my fetchRequest has, or needs to have two separate predicates that are completely independent.

One is for searching in the searchBar and one is for displaying information in the actual table view.

When I have both active, only one works.

Here's the predicates:

```
if ([self.personSearchBar.text length] > 0)
{
    NSPredicate *personPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY name CONTAINS[c] %@", self.personSearchBar.text]; 
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:personPredicate];
}

NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"transactions.whoBy.@count !=0"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:p];
```

So as you can see, there are two independent predicates, but both need to be active and working because in this state right now, the searching does not actually work but if I comment out the NSPredicate *p, it does.

Should I be using compound predicates and if so, how would I string these independent predicates together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an `NSCompoundPredicate` to combine them. Add each of your predicates to an array as you determine that you need them. Then use `andPredicateWithSubpredicates:` or `orPredicateWithSubpredicates:` depending on whether you require both or either of the predicates to apply to all of the results.

Comment: Thanks so much @Wain - that was exactly it (used the andPredicate). Thanks again!